# Saved draft page doesn't update after edit in iOS-app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open "Saved draft" page with no drafts:

   > [image: NoDrafts]
2. Tap "Ask a question" and set a title:

   > [image: NewQuestion]
3. Tap "Cancel" and "Save Draft":

   > [image: SaveDraft]
4. "Saved draft" page is empty like in step 1 (expected: one saved draft).
5. Tap "Saved draft" tab to refresh. One draft appears:

   > [image: OneDraft]
6. Delete draft via swipe. Draft deleted, but no link appears as in step 1 (expected: same page as in step 1):

   > [image: Empty]
7. Refresh page via tapping on the tab shows page as in step 1.

---

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)